# hide div on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a webpage that works for js and none-js visitors. For js-visitors the start image shall fade in, so it has to be hidden before. At the moment it is hidden too late, namely when the js has loaded. I cannot hide it by default , because in this case none-js visitors will not see it. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div class="startImage">...</div>
```

JS

```
 $('.startImage').hide().delay(200).fadeIn(200);
```

Comment: What would be a non-js visitor?

Comment: Try having `.startImage` set to `display:none`, then `fadeIn`onload.  If no JS, change the style of `.startImage` in <noscript> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use css to fade the div in then.

```
.startImage {
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera */
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Working JSFiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/bpzpb00q/

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.startImage {
display:none;
}
```

HEAD

```
<noscript>
  <style>.startImage {display:block}
  </style>
</noscript>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.startImage').fadeIn(200)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case `<noscript>` tag would be useful, add 2 same elements and and one warp with `<noscript>` tag and another element with css properly `display:none`

```
<noscript>
 <div class="startImage">...</div>
</noscript>
<div class="startImage forJS" style="display:none">...</div>
```

And target `<selector>` `$(".startImage.forJS")`

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.startImage.forJS').delay(200).fadeIn(200);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<noscript>` tag for the non JavaScript users and duplicate its content for the JavaScript users.

To the duplicated content add a class modifier like `.hidden` to set it to `display: none` by default. Apply your `fadeIn` function to it.

If you don't like the duplication you could have the JavaScript take the content from the `<noscript>` tag create a DOM element from it and inject it into the page.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#box').delay(200).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #c66;
  background-color: #f99;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 24px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<noscript>
  <div class="box">Content</div>
</noscript>
<div id="box" class="box hidden">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the `<noscript>` tag, like so:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#startImage img").css("opacity", "1");
});
```

```css
#startImage img {
 -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        #startImage img {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
<style type="text/css">
    #startImage img {
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
<div id="startImage">
    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/CMS/StaticContent/1391099215267_hero2.jpg" alt="Hero2" />
</div>
```

Even though it doesn't seem to work when you run the code snippet, the following [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/6yqcp3pc/) should work in the 5 major browsers.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using the fadeIn(200) to the "startImage" class 
then there is no need to hide the selector as well as not need to give delay
so 
that above method is right try it